# This Csrf script sometimes returns the $hash null

Tags: php, ajax

This is my csrf script. It sometimes returns the hash as null, resulting in my feed to not be displayed. I request the feed with ajax and send the token through that. Now, can anybody help figure out why this would return null only from time to time? Am I just not seeing the issue here?

```
    /* Cross-site request forgery attack prevention */
    class CsrfProtection {
        private $previous_hash;
        public  $hash;

        public function __construct() {

            /* Generate a new token */
            $token = md5(time() + time());

            /* Save the previous hash, if there is none then add the new token */
            $this->previous_hash = (isset($_SESSION['token'])) ? $_SESSION['token'] : $token;

            /* Save the new session / variable */
            if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'index.php') $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
            @$this->hash = $_SESSION['token'];

        }

        /* Check if post/get iprevious token is valid when sending data to the server */
        public function is_valid($key = 'token') {

            return (isset($_POST[$key]) && ($_POST[$key] === $this->previous_hash)) || (isset($_GET[$key]) && ($_GET[$key] === $this->previous_hash));

        }
    }
```

Everytime I call on a page, I use $token = new CsrfProtection();

Comment: Hash is null if the token is not set in the session. btw consider using an other method to create a token instead of time()

Comment: Hm, I didn't even notice the index.php, thanks :)